# How to make taxonomy_menu and block_menu in Drupal6 work together?

Tags: drupal, menu, taxonomy

I'm using taxonomy_menu module to render a two level menu from my taxonomy vocabulary. So far so good.

Troubles began when I decided to output levels of the menu separately. I've always used block_menu module for such tasks. I created two menu blocks and set them to display just the first and the second levels.

To my surprise, the second level block never shows up. I've done some debugging in menu_block. Looks like menu_tree_build (in block_menu) function depends on menu_tree_page_data (in menu) to get the active trails data. And the latter fails to deliver it for menus based on taxonomy.

Can anyone propose a workaround? What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

[Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module should be useful for this. It allows to show menu blocks and set the level of menu structure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I said block_menu… I actually meant menu_block, of course. But looks like it doesn't work correctly together with menus built by taxonomy_menu. My question was about possible workarounds.